# is it possible to determine the location of any networked device and mark them with a camera

Tags: detection

is it possible to use a cell phone to determine the location of the devices in the same network and highlight them on a camera like in watch dogs? as long as it is a portable solution and it can work anywhere you have a wifi network you can run pings on. this is my first question here on stack exchange and I am sorry if I posted in the wrong sector. Thx.
p.s: ok, a little revise, is it possible to use three accurate enough bluetooth cards hidden in a jacket to triangulate the location and calculate the wifi mac address based on the bluetooth mac address.

Answer (score 0):

No - there are no corresponding ID between a physical device and the way the device appears on a network.

Comment: well, is it possible to create some sort of external device that is portable enough to carry, but accurate enough to determine the location?

Comment: nope, IP networked devices are assigned an IP address that are generally assigned when the device connects to the network. On top of that, these addresses are not unique as private IP addresses are reused. For example, 192.168.1.1 is the IP address that almost all home routers use. Can't use that to identify the device.

You can try to identify by mac address, which generally is a unique ID for the device, but that does not give you any more info where it is physically located.

So no, you can't. You would need the device to broadcast some ID and triangulate physical location.

Comment: that is what i thought, i edited the question and said to use three accurate hidden bluetooth cards to triangulate the device and find the bluetooth mac address of the device, than use that to calculate the wifi mac address.

Comment: No, bluetooth is not compatible with wifi.